# How do I call an Excel macro from Python using xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I've read the [API docs](http://docs.xlwings.org/api.html) for xlwings, and played around with Workbook and Sheet objects in the interpreter, but I can't figure out how to call a macro from Python.

How do I use xlwings to call an Excel macro from Python?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is not implemented yet, but there's an open issue for it, see [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/134). In the meantime, you can work around it like so (this is for Windows, but the Mac version works accordingly, see again in the [issue](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/134)):

```
from xlwings import Workbook
wb = Workbook(...)
wb.application.xl_app.Run("your_macro")
```

**update**: for more recent versions, you have to do:

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Application
wb = Workbook(...)
Application(wb).xl_app.Run("your_macro")
```

**update 2**: This functionality is now natively supported from >=v0.7.1. Let's assume, there is a VBA function `YourMacro` that sums up two numbers:

```
>>> import xlwings as xw
>>> wb = xw.Book(r'C:\path\to\mybook.xlsm')
>>> your_macro = wb.macro('YourMacro')
>>> your_macro(1, 2)
3.0
```

Answer (score 5):

I got issues when I updated xlwings to 0.9+ version.
To run vba macro with xlwings, I used the code written below for running macros inside the personal workbook (PERSONAL.XLSB).
The updated code no2 of Felix didn't work for me, for macro inside the personal workbook.

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book(excel_file_path)
app = wb.app
# into brackets, the path of the macro
macro_vba = app.macro("'PERSONAL.XLSB'!my_macro") 
macro_vba()
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for this! And for completeness' sake: import xlwings as xw ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a late answer, but all the ways posted above didn't work for me.
But I have found another way, by using the awesome api-interface provided by xlwings.

Here is my code I used to run a macro:

```
xlApp = xw.App(visible=False)
wb= xw.books.open('.\\Path\\To\\File.xlsm')
a = xlApp.api.Application.Run("macroTest")
```

My macro opened a MsgBox and returned the value 1 just for test and it worked very well.
Although one should avoid using MsgBox, since it was opened in background.

Btw. the api-interface is available in many (when not all) objects and it is really powerfull if you are used to VBA programming.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way if you already open a excel.

```
xw.apps.active.macro('yourMacro')(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Felix Zumstein's answer and all other answers here, please ensure you have disabled Macro settings as you may face COM issues later.

You can change that under,

File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Macro Settings > Enable all macros (not recommended...)