# Set_column not working until manually activatiing each cell

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Been trying to get the set_column to work still. Having problems getting Pandas to work, so have been doing it just in xlsxwriter.  Right now am using:
'worksheet.set_column('D:D',None,format4)'  - this only seems to work when I go into the xlsx file and actually activate each cell in the "D" column.  Is there some way of activating each cell so that I wouldn't have to do it manually?

Thanks in advance.

```
import xlsxwriter,os,sys,datetime
now=datetime.datetime.now()
def main():
    platform=sys.platform
    if platform.find('win')>=0:
        TheSlash='\\'
    else:
        TheSlash='/'
    output = '%s-%s.xlsx' % ('XlsxSample',now.strftime("%m%d%Y-%H%M"))
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'strings_to_numbers':True,'default_date_format':'mm/dd/yy hh:mm'})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    count=0
    counter=0
    format=workbook.add_format({'font_size':'8','border':True})
    formatdict={'num_format':'mm/dd/yy hh:mm'}
    format4=workbook.add_format(formatdict)
    cur =('Pole1','33.62283963','-90.54639967','4/20/16 11:43','-90.54640226','33.62116957','5207069','25-04','50','3','PRIMARY','PGC')
    for name in cur:
        worksheet.write(counter, count, name,format)
        count+=1
    counter+=1
    worksheet.set_column('D:D',None,format4)
    workbook.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

as stated above - date format only seems to activate if you get into the "D" cell itself with the cursor.

Comment: There is no known issue with `set_column()`. Can you post a small complete working example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Working Sample to follow

Comment: Side note: You do a little test to assign `TheSlash`, which isn't used at all in your sample code. But I am guessing that in your full-blown program (which you have not included here), you use `TheSlash` in path names. Generally, you do not have to know the separator; in most contexts, you can just use a regular slash, even on Windows. If you REALLY, REALLY must know the primary path separator for your platform, then just use `os.sep` instead of your rigamarole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the column date format isn't showing up in the column cells is that the program is overwriting it with a cell format here:

```
for name in cur:
    worksheet.write(counter, count, name,format)
    count+=1
```

In XlsxWriter, as in Excel, a cell format overrides a column format.

If you want to have a cell or column format that is the result of 2 combined formats you will need to create a new format that combines those formats and apply it to the cells or the column.

**Update**: Also, I just noticed that you are writing a string in column D. Dates in Excel are formatted numbers. This is probably why you see the cell data change when you hit return. Excel is converting the date-like string into a formatted number displayed as a date. In XlsxWriter you will need to do the conversion. See the [Working with Dates and Time](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html) section of the XlsxWriter docs.

Comment: So, would it work then if I did an if/else statement such as    `if count==3:  ``    worksheet.write(counter,count,name,format4)  ``else:  ``    worksheet.write(counter,count,name,format)  `

Comment: In theory yes but you will also need to convert the strings in column D to Excel dates. See my update.

Comment: Got it working, although it took me a while to figure out I needed to do a `datetime.datetime.strptime()` call.  Helps me a lot as I have a ton of reports with dates to pull out of a db.  Thanks for the help - figured I would add the note about the datetime setup also.

Answer (score 3):

You need change format using [datetime.datetime.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

Example

```
import datetime
datetime_result = datetime.dateime.strptime('04/20/16 11:43', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
format5 = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'mm/dd/yy hh:mm'})
worksheet.write('A5', datetime_result, format5)
```

Refer to [Working with Dates and Time](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html) in XlsxWriter docs.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, `Columns("D").Select` does what you want. If you are running from an external script, you might be able to save a VBA macro and run it with a technique like this: [How do I call an Excel macro from Python using xlwings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308455/how-do-i-call-an-excel-macro-from-python-using-xlwings).

Comment: Working Sample to follow: